# Force react to wait for state change (fetching data)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my link shortening app I was doing everything in one function and now I would like to split it into smaller functions but there is a problem when it comes to fetching. When I fetch data from api, js is waiting for it to be fetched but next functions are being processed before data is saved in a state. It results in component being rendered without needed data because render starts before state is ready. How can I fix it?

```
const checkLink = () => {
    if (!nextLink) {
      setErrorMsg("Please add link");
      return false;
    } else if (!nextLink.match(linkRegex)) {
      setErrorMsg("That's not a link");
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };
  const fetchShortenedLink = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch(
      `https://api.shrtco.de/v2/shorten?url=${nextLink}`
    );
    if (!response.ok) {
      setErrorMsg(`An error has occured: ${response.status}`);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } else {
      const data = await response.json();
      await setFetchedLink(data.result.short_link)
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
  const shortenLink = async () => {
    checkLink();
    await fetchShortenedLink();
    setLinkArr((prev) => [
      ...prev,
      {
        id: prev.length === 0 ? 1 : prev[prev.length - 1].id + 1,
        long: nextLink,
        short: fetchedLink,
      },
    ]);
    setNextLink("");
    scrollToLink();
  };
```

Comment: You can't wait for the state update. Nesting functions like this don't make it any more readable for me. Usually, you should return from one function before you start the next one.

Answer (score 1):

The "react" way of doing this would be to use `useEffect()` and add the state change you want to wait for in the dependency array. Using your own example:

```
const shortenLink = async () => {
  checkLink();
  await fetchShortenedLink();
  setLinkArr(...); 
  setNextLink("");
};

useEffect(
  () => { scrollToLink() }, // Whatever you want to do after the state changes
  [linkArray, nextLink]     // Add the state you changed in this dependency array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting State in React is async and you can't await on it. But you could achieve this by different methods.

You could possibly use a React Ref to store the state of the state variable. Then update the state variable with the react ref. This will render a page refresh, and then use the React Ref in the async function.

```
const stateRef = React.useRef().current
const [state,setState] = useState(stateRef);

async function some() {
  stateRef = { some: 'value' }
  setState(stateRef) // Triggers re-render
  
  await some2();
}

async function some2() {
  await someHTTPFunctionCall(stateRef.some)
  stateRef = null;
  setState(stateRef) // Triggers re-render
}
```